# crystal report 8 configure group name

Tags: crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report. And I got some legacy crystal report 8.0 to support. One of the reports has following:

group 3: city (details)

group 2: area(sum of group 3)

group 1: region (sum of group 2)

Now the problem is group 2 shows wrong area name. There is only area code from the underlying stored procedure (sql server), so there is must be something in the report that match the area code to some wrong area names. But I can't find how it did it. When I click the field of area name, there is just a pop up window showing 'group #2 name'. I have looked into 'change group expert' and only see it's grouped by area code (which is expected), nothing about group name. Just don't know how group name are set in crystal report?

The screen shot:

The South East (area name) below is wrong. The '001' (area code) is correct.This is group #2a
[image]

This is the report definition, you can see the Group #2 Name, I have right clicked on it.
[image]

When I try insert a group, I can see the group name by formula. But where can I see/edit the current group 2?

[image]

[image]

In the change group, the group 2 name seems to be grayed out. So where the group name comes from?

The answer is based on Ally's comment. The group name is actually from the Specified Order tab. Anyway, thanks for everyone's input.

[image]

Comment: If there is nothing much in header then just delete the group and recreate it.

Comment: I want to know how the group names got set up. Group 2 have names like 'south east', 'east', 'west', etc. The area code for group 2 are like '001', '002' etc, which are from a database field. I think there should be some kind of mapping between these two in crystal report but couldn't find it.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your crystal report? That will help to recognise the cause.

Comment: If it has a Specified Order on the Group, that is where the Group Name is coming from.

Comment: Does the `Branch Name` still exist as a field in the result of the procedure?

Comment: @Ally Yes, you are right. I have just returned from a sick leave. And you are absolutely correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Ally if you can put your comment in an answer, I can then pick yours as correct answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thotwielder,

to answer your question about the groups:
To see how the groups are made up, right-click in the field explorer and click on Group Expert. You can also get there by right-clicking on a group header.
[image: See screenshot for Group Expert]
Once you click on the Group Expert, you will see a box open. [image: See the second screenshot]
This will show you the fields that make up the groups. You can re-sort the order or even add/remove groups.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: They're using Crystal Reports 8 aka Crystal Reports from many years ago and I don't know if that functionality is available.

Comment: Judging from his description it's the report that is from Crystal Reports 8, not the software he's using, unless I'm misunderstanding. If he's really using Crystal Reports 8, then under the common tab in Change Group Option he should just be able to change the field using the drop-down arrow to the field he wants to group by.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am using crystal report 8.

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understand your problem. There is nothing to do with the version of the crystal reports you are usinig.

1. Your group is grouped by area code so this problem won't be solved by changing the group or using change group option.
2. I doubt `001` is area code (Grouped one) and `South east` is the database field placed in group2. I would suggest you to check the formula fields for name `Group #2 Name` and check the database field place in that group. If it is wrong then place the appropriate value over there.

Hope this helps to solve your problem.